# Un-applying certain tags in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone help me a bit?

I'm using bootstrap, and I do not want bootstrap to change a certain tag (by id,class or element). How can I change the behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some code? what do you mean don't want bootstrap to change.

Comment: what is the behaviour you need to change?

Comment: let's say in MaterializeCSS, we have a class 'browser-default' which restores the tag styles and attributes to default. Is there a similar thing in Bootstrap?

Comment: Please show what you are trying , add your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these could be added to your main css file. Using the class browser-default would then remove all styles from an element.

```
.browser-default {
    all: initial;
}

.browser-default {
    all: initial !important;
}
```